# How to print prepared statement in mysql php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to print prepared statement with bind parameters, i have seen some answer but they are not working. I have tried following things:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE subcategory_id IN (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $subCategoryIds);
    $stmt->execute();
    print_r($stmt->__toString());
    echo $stmt->fullQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print the object and can find for what you are looking. object contains all the method and properties the class contains you can try :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($stmt);
exit;
```